# SSIS Logging and auditing - What are all the events i need to select to capture task start and end time along with rows processed?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

What are all the events i need to select to capture task start and end time along with rows processed in SSIS logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Package StartTime**: The system variable `StartTime` has the time that the package started to run.
**Container StartTime**: The system variable `ContainerStartTime` has the start time of the container.

There is no end time AFAIK. The way I handle this is by doing a `GETDATE()` to get the current-date and time at the appropriate place / event in my Control Flow within the SSIS Package.

Example: For auditing all our packages, I use a custom Audit table that contains summary info like the name of the package, the `ExecutionInstanceGUID`, ETL / CRUD rowcounts etc, and the Start and End time for the package.

At the beginning of each package, I create an Audit row with all the information I have in hand, and most of them are either constants or are values sourced from System variables.

[image]

Then at the end of my Control Flow, I update the same Audit Row with the current datetime for the `EndTime` / `StopTime` and update other status fields.

[image]

As for Rows Process, the `OnInformation` event has this wherever it is relevant, but tapping into that event means you get a lot of noise i.e. event infos you don't care about. So I usually do an explicit `ROWCOUNT` in my Control Flow or Data Flow and store it in a Variable at the appropriate scope for use later.

#### Row Count in Control Flow is done using a SELECT Statement

[image]

The SQL to get row count

[image]

The variable set to capture the row count from the SQL

[image]

#### Row Count in Data Flow is done using the ROWCOUNT Transform Toolbox Component.

[image]

Here's where a variable is assigned inside that ROWCOUNT component, to capture the count.

[image]